# Zf2 ViewModel vs JsonModel

Tags: zend-framework2

I have been using both ViewModel and JsonModel in my Zf2 project. What I am trying to know is which is better to use when an ajax call is made and html is to be rendered into a div ?

```
return new ViewModel(array());

or

return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array());
```

Does both have the same efficiency ? or there is some other difference which I have not understood yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsonModel is child class of the ViewModel, it just disables layout, serializes all variables into json and returns it.

If you want to create/render the HTML markup on-the-fly using javascript, returning the data using `JsonModel` would be better on most cases. If you don't need to manipulate HTML part after fetching it via ajax call, use `ViewModel` : prepare HTML markup, disable layout by calling `setTerminal(true)` and return it.

Comment: +1 You can render the HTML and include it within the JSON response by using the renderer `$html = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer')->render($viewModel);`

Comment: @AlexP and foozy, thank you so much, is there an speed difference between the approaches ? What I do is call ajax, and instead of loading the whole page on success, replace the html of the specific div element